# My static files are not coming in my Django API project after deploying it in AWS EC2

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have created a simple API with django but after deploying it on AWS EC2 the admin panel is not showing any CSS or design. Please Help.

Like This:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54ISt.png)

nginx file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/sweetraga_django/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    }
}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: try using [whitenoise](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)